# What options are there to get stock data from a ASP website that no longer exists?

Tags: php, asp.net, codeigniter

I have this PHP code using codeigniter as a framework which all is doing is getting the latest information from the Google stock:

```
{ section name="company" loop=$stock}

   <hr noshade size="1" width="100%">
   <table width="100%" border="0">

   <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><b>{$stock[company].symbol}: {$stock[company].name}</b></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      {if $stock[company].symbol == "Google"}
      <td><b><a href="http://www.nasdaq.com/asp/quotes_multi.asp?mode=stock&symbol=googl">Google - NASDAQ</a></b></td>
     {else}
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     {/if}
     <td colspan="4"><div align="right">{$stock[company].date}, 
{if $stock[company].time != ""}
   {$stock[company].time|date_format:"%I:%M%p"} ET
{/if}
{if $stock[company].status != ""}
   - {$stock[company].status}
{/if}</div></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>Last Sale:</td>
      <td><div align="right"><b>$&nbsp;{$stock[company].price_last}</b></div></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Net Change:</td>
      <td><div align="right">$&nbsp;{$stock[company].dchangeu} 
      {if $stock[company].direction == "up"}
         <img src="/images/greenArrowSmall.gif" alt="" height="11" width="11" alt="^"> {$stock[company].pchange}%
      {else if $stock[company].direction == "down"}
         <img src="/images/redArrowSmall.gif" alt="" height="11" width="11" alt="v"> {$stock[company].pchange}%
      {/if}
      </div></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>Today's High:</td>
      <td><div align="right">$&nbsp;{$stock[company].price_max|string_format:"%.2f"}</div></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Today's Low:</td>
      <td><div align="right">$&nbsp;{$stock[company].price_min|string_format:"%.2f"}</div></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>Share Volume:</td>
      <td><div align="right">{$stock[company].volume}</div></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Previous Close:</td>
      <td><div align="right">$&nbsp;{$stock[company].previous|string_format:"%.2f"}</div></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>Best Bid:</td>
      {if $stock[company].best_bid != ""}
      <td><div align="right">$&nbsp;{$stock[company].best_bid|string_format:"%.2f"}</div></td>
      {else}
      <td><div align="right">unavailable</div></td>
      {/if}
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Best Ask:</td>
      {if $stock[company].best_ask != ""}
      <td><div align="right">$&nbsp;{$stock[company].best_ask|string_format:"%.2f"}</div></td>
 {else}
      <td><div align="right">unavailable</div></td>
      {/if}
   </tr>

   </table>

{/section}
```

the URL that this code was using seems like it no longer exists: http://www.nasdaq.com/asp/quotes_multi.asp?mode=stock&symbol=googl 
since it returns a "NOT FOUND" response.

I don't think nasdaq will make this .asp page available since I'm reading that ASP is old, what would be the best possible solution to make the least changes on the code?

I googled if there are any other websites offering that asp page but there's none, only APIs returning data in JSON format, which will have a big impact on my code if I want to update it to  be able to get JSON variables, are there any other alternatives for this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you give is now probably [this one](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/googl).
But I suspect your real interest is populating `$stock` variable.

Parsing json data is actually quite easy, so the impact on your code may not be as big as you think.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the new URL. And by parsing JSON data I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean, the page doesn't contain JSON data (I might be wrong), and I don't know much about this codeigniter framework, is there any help you might please provide for this? Thank you so much!

Comment: My JSON comment was not about the linked page it was about using an API that returns JSON. Was the variable `$stock` being filled with data from the old URL?

Comment: Yes, I haven't modified anything in the code. It seems like they just at some point just stopped using that page. I have an example in how it used to look way before: http://web.archive.org/web/20100208013123/http://quotes.nasdaq.com/Quote.dll?page=multi&mode=stock&mode=Stock&Symbol=hain

Comment: Is that what your site displayed or is that the old .asp page? Is that the page where you got your data for `$stock`?

Comment: That was what the nasdaq asp page look like before. And that's correct, that's how the variable $stock was being populated.